# magento. Редактирование темы. Как создать страницу для товара

Tags: magento

Как создать отдельную страницу для товара в Magento? Смог только разобраться как изменять такие стандартные блоки, как футер, хедер и контент.

Comment: Magento 1 или 2? Что вы понимаете под "создать отдельную страницу для товара в Magento" (она там есть по умолчанию catalog/product/view/id/{id})? Рискну предположить что вы хотели бы изменить какие-то конкретные блоки в лэйауте. Если это так, то дополните пожалуйста ваш вопрос, так будет проще помочь :)